# extproc env variables oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g, listener

I have oracle 11g with extproc separately configured in listener.ora.

Users report some environmental variables that should be exported are not set.

From where does extproc gets it environment besides ENV in its definition in listener.ora? They come from shell that started listener? Why variables included in ENV do not appear?

How could I efficiently check what env variabls extproc has set?

Answer (score 1):

11g
Oracle recommends that we configure the EXTPROC by altering the extproc.ora file rather than configure the listener for Oracle 11g.
 The extproc.ora file is located in the ORACLE_HOME\hs\admin directory.